# Formula to give the value of the cell next to the 3 largest values that meet a criteria in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, offset, largenumber

I am creating a spreadsheet that is using VLOOKUP to give a bunch of data based on a dropdown box.

It is a fairly large list (the screenshot does not do it justice), and the data is part of a table that has new lines added regularly. Because of this, when looking at the range, it will need to be in a format of "TABLE1[COLUMN1]" instead of "A1:A15" for example.

Basically I am after 3 separate cells to display the cell next to the 3 highest values that meet the criteria. For example, in the screenshot below A17 = AAA. Therefore I want cell C17 to show the value next to the highest value where TABLE1[COLUMN1] = "AAA". In this example, Cells C17:C19 will show "WWW", "XXX" and "VVV" respectively.

I am not sure how well I explained this, as I am very new to excel. So if you need any further information, please do not hesitate to let me know!

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the New Dynamic Array Formula:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Table1,Table1[COLUMN1]=F1),2,-1),0,3),{1;2;3})
```

place it in the first cell and Excel will fill it down.

`,2,` in the sort refers to the 2nd column relatively in the table.  Change that to the column number in the table which has the numbers.  `,3` refers to the relative column to return, in my case the third.

[image]

---

Without the Dynamic Array formula one needs to put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Table1[COLUMN2])/((Table1[COLUMN2]=AGGREGATE(14,7,Table1[COLUMN2]/(Table1[COLUMN1]=$F$1),ROW(1:1)))*(Table1[COLUMN1]=$F$1)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Going to follow your lead as much as possible in prioritizing the new formulas. We need more answers incorporating them.

Comment: Just like MAXIFS and MINIFS a couple years ago.  Need to keep Microsoft making money. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I use,

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$13,INDEX(MATCH($G$2&LARGE(($C$2:$C$13=$G$2)*$D$2:$D$13,ROW(A1)),$C$2:$C$13&$D$2:$D$13,0),0))
```

[image]